# Run sonar on android project: The class 'foo.bar.R$string' could not be matched to its original source file

Tags: android, resources, sonarqube, findbugs

When I run sonar analysis of my android project, I always get lots of messages about .class files generated by Android resource compilation like following

> Run sonar: The class 'foo.bar.R$string' could not be matched to its
>   original source file. It might be a dynamically generated class.

I guess these messages come from Findbugs.

I have tried to exclude `**/R.class` `**/R$*.class` from sonar analysis, but no luck.

Any ideas on how to get rid of such messages?

Comment: Do you use the Findbugs plugin for SonarQube?

Comment: Yes I do use that plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved with `sonar.findbugs.excludesFilters` property

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.findbugs.excludesFilters', 'findbugs-filter.xml'
    }
}
```

and findbugs-filter.xml is

```
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <Or>
            <Class name="~.*\.R\$.*"/>
            <Class name="~.*\.Manifest\$.*"/>
        </Or>
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```